# Python assiggnment about number listing

Tags: python

Write a program in python whose input is a positive integer and displays the next ten integers in a sequence.

The function should return the next number as an integer given the previous integer num. The function should return num/2 if num is even. Otherwise it should return 3*num - 1. The numbers should print on individual lines. I'm not getting any syntax errors so I'm confused.

```
def f(x):
        numlist = [x]
        if x%2 == 0:
                numlist.append(int(x/2))
        else:
                numlist.append(int(x*3 - 1))
        numlist.remove(x)
        return numlist

number = int(input())
for i in f(number):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Confused about what? Do you get incorrect output?

Comment: Please paste the output you are getting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: If you want a sequence like x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), you need some kind of recursion or loop. Currently you are looping over f(x) which is just 1 number.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to mention here:

1. Your `for-loop` is wrong. Loop iterates on iterable objects in your case `f(x)` returns a `list` which is iterable, but it is not making any sense. Because you have only one value in the list.
2. You should return an `integer` from the function and run `f(x)` in a for loop for 10 times.

Use this code:

```
def f(x):
    # No need to use List here you just want to return one integer
    if x%2 == 0:
        x = int(x/2)
    else:
        x = int(x*3 - 1)
    return x
    
number = int(input())
per = f(number)

# Your For loop was wrong. This is how it should be
for i in range(10):
    print(per, end=' ') # print result 
    per = f(per)        # calculate next result
```

**Output:**

> 97
>
> 290 145 434 217 650 325 974 487 1460 730